# Merging 2 objects, no loose parts

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, selection-tools

I would like to ask if there is a way to merge 2 objects together in a way that later it will not be separable if I hit "Separate by loose parts".

I am facing this problem when I am making a torch like object which consists of two objects, an icosphere and an elongated cube. When I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to merge them, it's fine because it's only one object. But after I use the array modifier to make a lot of torches and then separate them by loose parts, I get all the icospheres and cubes separated too, not just the torches.

I have no idea how to solve this problem. I will appreciate any help. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to connect the meshes with at least 1 vertex?

Comment: No, I don't know how could I do that.

Comment: Do your parts of the torch have to be visually separated?

Comment: Yes, but only visually. And I have tried to merge the two objects and then in edit mode I selected one vertice of the cube and one vertice of the icosphere, but I just wasn't able to connect them with Mesh -> Vertices -> Connect.

Comment: I suppose Merge will be the appropriate one, or maybe creating an edge between the vertices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can avoid the separation of the two objects after hitting the **Separate by loose parts** in these steps:

1. Merge the two objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
2. Go to *Edit Mode* and *select 2 vertices*, one belongs to the first object and the second belongs to the second object
3. Merge the vertices with <kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: Can you add details of the steps for the solution and a screenshot so it will be crear for other people?

Comment: Corrected CTRL+M to ALT+M. Hope that was your idea. CTRL+M does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this problem in 2.8 and having no luck finding fixes online. But I've just found a fix, so I hope this comment might help someone in the same position. Have a look at a plugin named "Fast Carve". It has a great set of tools similar to Adobe Illustrator's Pathfinder tools. Including a Union button.
Use this to join your 2 objects without needing to merge vertices. Hope this helps someone.